# GKE ingress controller svc externalTrafficPolicy to Local

Tags: kubernetes, gke-networking

In order to get the real client ip,I change the ingress controller svc(LoadBalancer type)   externalTrafficPolicy to Local.But once I set the externalTrafficPolicy to Local,all ingress will can't access.
So I would like to know,how can I get the client ip in ingress-nginx controller  on GKE.

Comment: How are you trying to get the real client ip? Did you check the "X-Forwarder-For" header?

Comment: I have solved this problem by set externalTrafficPolicy to Local.Couldn’t access ingress after I set externalTrafficPolicy to Local before. It seemed that there was a problem with that version of ingress. I changed the version and it was fine.